# python multiprocessing to receive snmp alerts

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, snmp, pysnmp

I want my code to be able to receive SNMP alerts. I am using `pysnmp` module of python. I am creating a new process for a trap listener. I am using `multiprocessing` module. The trap listener receives snmp alert messages and sends it to my main process which will conduct some calculations on them. But how do I pass that message data to my parent process? I wanted to create a queue. But since the snmp data is being received by function `cbFun()` I don't know how to pass it to `trapReceiver()`. A simple return function won't work.

I thought I could make the queue a global variable. Is that a good idea?

My other alternative is writing to a file in the `cbFun` and reading from it in my main process.

What is the best way to approach this?

When I execute the code given below, the child process is printing out the received snmp messages, but I am not able to print it from the parent process. What am I doing wrong?

```
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.carrier.asynsock.dgram import udp, udp6
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import ntfrcv
from multiprocessing import Process
import Queue

q = Queue.Queue()

def trapListener():
    # Create SNMP engine with autogenernated engineID and pre-bound
    # to socket transport dispatcher

    snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()

    # Transport setup

    # UDP over IPv4
    config.addSocketTransport(
        snmpEngine,
        udp.domainName,
        udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('10.94.175.171', 162))
    )

    # SNMPv1/2c setup

    # SecurityName <-> CommunityName mapping
    config.addV1System(snmpEngine,'my-area', 'public')


    # Register SNMP Application at the SNMP engine
    ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(snmpEngine, cbFun)

    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1) # this job would never finish

    # Run I/O dispatcher which would receive queries and send confirmations
    try:
        snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
    except:
        snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
        raise
# Callback function for receiving notifications

def cbFun(snmpEngine,stateReference,
              contextEngineId, contextName,
              varBinds,
              cbCtx):
    (transportDomain, transportAddress ) = snmpEngine.msgAndPduDsp.getTransportInfo(stateReference)

    f=open('eventDescriptions.txt','r')
    print('Notification from %s, ContextEngineId "%s", ContextName "%s"' % (
                transportAddress, contextEngineId.prettyPrint(),
                contextName.prettyPrint()))

    for name, val in varBinds:
        if name.prettyPrint()=="1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.5.3.1.2.0":
            print('child: %s' % (val.prettyPrint()))
            q.put(val.prettyPrint())

if __name__=="__main__":
    p=Process(target=trapListener, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    print "parent: ", q.get()
    p.join()
```

Comment: I got my code to work. I made `cbFun` a nested function in `trapReceiver`. The queue variable was made local to main process and passed to `trapReceiver(q)`. I intend to add `Lock` too so the output from parent and child processes don't get mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use a closure for passing Queue object to cbFun. Something like this:

```
def getCbFun(queue): # closure
    def cbFun(snmpEngine,stateReference,
          contextEngineId, contextName,
          varBinds,
          cbCtx):
        ...
        queue.add(varBinds)
        ...
    return cbFun

...

# Shared queue object
queue = Queue()

# Register SNMP Application at the SNMP engine
ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(snmpEngine, getCbFun(queue))

...
```

So the idea if that cbFun() would use the queue object from the local scope of getCbFun() which is not global.

Comment: I realised my problem was dealing with the variable scope. Right now, I have made `cbFun` a nested function in `TrapReceiver` which solves the problem I think. Is that a good idea? The code is working for now. But if I face more problems, I will definitely try out your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I used it elsewhere in my code where I had a similar situation. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe it will be more  simple to use subprocess module.
you can create a new process with subprocess.Popen and than use the communicate method to send data to the process.

Comment: I thought `subprocess` was mostly used to run non-python code or commands in the shell. However, I gave it a go by putting `trapreceiver()` in a separate file and running it. It didn't work. The child process exits without waiting to receive traps.